# ObjectManager при задании опции clusterize: true не отображается объект типа Polygon

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Добрый день, заметил такую особенность в ObjectManager, наношу метки на карту через ObjectManager, в опициях ObjectManager выставляю  clusterize: true, по клику на карте должен добавиться объект типа Polygon, но он не добавляется, когда комментирую clusterize: true то объект типа Polygon на карте отображается. В чем проблема понять не могу.

```
ymaps.ready(function () {

var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [42.985329, 47.503824],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: ['zoomControl']
}),
objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({clusterize : true});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'data.json', false);
xhr.send();
if (xhr.status != 200) {
    console.log("bad");
    console.log(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    // пример вывода: 404: Not Found
} else {
    console.log("good");
    // responseText -- текст ответа.
}
objectManager.add(xhr.responseText);
map.geoObjects.add(objectManager)
map.events.add('click', function(){
console.log('privet');
objectManager.add(setCluster());
});
setCluster = function() {
 return {
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": 0,
  "options": {"fillColor": "#255F06", "strokeColor": "#255F06", "opacity": 0.5},
  "properties": {"balloonContent": "Содержимое балуна", "hintContent": "Текст подсказки"},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          55.801280971180454,
          37.552642822265625
        ],
        [
          55.81285742969946,
          37.518310546875
        ],
        [
          55.8367712028016,
          37.540283203125
        ],
        [
          55.80784138701898,
          37.57118225097656
        ],
        [
          55.801280971180454,
          37.552642822265625
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jez2a3bn/  тут пример есть, где clusterize: true, как только меням на false объект отображается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectManager не отображает неточечные объекты в режиме кластеризации.
Я вижу два пути решения этой проблемы:

1. Использовать RemoteObjectManager - он умеет отображать одновременно
   кластеры и неточечные объекты.
2. Добавить на карту два ObjectManager, один из которых будет с
   неточечными объектами и без кластеризации.

Comment: Спасибо!!! За совет, сделал с двумя ОМ, попытаюсь сделать с ROM

Comment: Не за что) Ответ можно признать лучшим, если помог!)

Comment: как это сделать??

Answer (score 1):

Прочтите внимательно документацию - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/#param-options.clusterize

При включенной кластеризации неточечные объекты будут игнорироваться.
Если вам нужно показать полигоны, добавьте их на карту через другой ObjectManager